# Select dropdown not showing selected value php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `Wordpress Settings API`. Everything works as it should except this `select` dropdown. When I select an option, the value echoed is correct but in the dropdown it displays the default first value i.e `6` and not the selected one. Where am I going wrong?

```
 public function someplugin_select() {
            $options = get_option( 'plugin_252calc');
            echo $options; //shows the correct value selected
            $items = array();
            for ($i=6; $i <=10; $i+= 0.1) 
            { 
                $items[] = $i;
            }

            echo '<select id="cf-nb" name="cf-nb">';
            foreach ( $items as $item )
            {
                echo '<option value="'. $item .'"';
                if ( $item == $options ) echo' selected="selected"';
                echo '>'. $item .'</option>';
            }

            echo '</select>';           

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two separate loops, you can do everything in just one `for` loop. In addition to that, you need to change your `someplugin_select()` method in the following way,

```
public function someplugin_select() {
    $options = round(floatval(get_option( 'plugin_252calc')), 1);
    echo '<select id="cf-nb" name="cf-nb">';
    for ($i = 6.0; $i <= 10.0; $i += 0.1){ 
        $output = '<option value="'. $i .'"';
        if ( $options == round($i, 1) ){
            $output .= ' selected="selected"';
        }
        $output .= '>'. $i .'</option>';
        echo $output;
    }
    echo '</select>';         
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the code, but while `get_option` is returning the correct selected value, the dropdown still displays the first value `6` regardless of my selection.

Comment: @input Do `var_dump($options);` and tell me what it is showing, both the value and type.

Comment: This is the output of `var_dump`  `string(3) "7.5"`

Comment: @input I've updated my answer along with the solution code snippet. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. Much appreciated.